# Get list of all items of a generic type from list which could contain other types

Tags: c#, linq, generics

Okay, this is tricky.  Say I have a list:

```
List<Foo> MyList;
```

`Foo` is a common abstract class which is used for all components in the system.  Some of these component classes are generic:

```
public class Bar<T> : Foo
{
    public void MethodCommonToAllBar()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

And some classes may extend the generic ones:

```
public class Baz : Bar<int>
public class Bat : Bar<string>
```

I'd like a way to extract from `MyList` a set of all objects of type `Bar<anything>`, so that I may call `MethodCommonToAllBar()` on each of those things.  If it weren't for the generic here, I could use a line like:

```
foreach (Baz baz in MyList.Where(x => x is Baz))
{
    baz.MethodCommonToAllBar();
}
foreach (Bat bat in MyList.Where(x => x is Bat))
{
    bat.MethodCommonToAllBar();
}
```

or even

```
foreach (Bar<int> bar in MyList.Where(x => x is Bar<int>))
{
    bar.MethodCommonToAllBar();
}
foreach (Bar<string> bar in MyList.Where(x => x is Bar<string>))
{
    bar.MethodCommonToAllBar();
}
```

But there doesn't seem to be any way to get all objects of any type of `Bar` unless I treat each potential subtype separately.  Is there a workaround for this?  Assume that I can't change the class structure in any way.  (I could, but it's a big project, and such a change would impact a lot of people, so it's unlikely I'd get it approved.  Ideally, I'd add another non-generic class between `Foo` and `Bar<T>` in the hierarchy to store that method and any other such common things and just search for that.  But it's a bit late in the game to go refactoring that now.)  I can also see a workaround involving Reflection, but that seems like overkill, and would likely incur a performance hit to boot.  Is there any other way to handle this cleanly?

Comment: And of course you can't move the method to `Foo`. Some situation. I think the only right decision is to introduce this class in-between. Usually it's now or never with these kinds of design decisions. And "never" can be very expensive in the long run.... I've heard "not now" too often and many of them I still regret.

Answer (score 3):

You must you be aware of the fact that the two types `Bar<X>` and `Bar<Y>` are not compatible! They are just two different types deriving from a common ancestor. The fact that they are both concrete implementations of the same open generic type makes no difference.
And how do you want to process them? Assume that you retrieved an object of type `Bar<?>` of an unknown generic type from the list and that you have a method

```
void ProcessBar<T>() { ... }
```

Where do you know the right value of `T` from? Note that `T` is resolved at compile time, not at runtime! This is what generics are for: to provide certain flexibility by keeping type safety. And type safety can only be achieved at compile time.

One way of solving this problem is in fact to introduce a non-generic intermediate type in your inheritance hierarchy. If you cannot change the inheritance hierachy, let all `Bar<T>` implement a non-generic interface `IBar`

```
public interface IBar
{
    void MethodCommonToAllBar();
}
```

and simply filter your list with

```
foreach (IBar bar in MyList.OfType<IBar>())
{
    bar.MethodCommonToAllBar(); // Method defined in IBar.
}
```

Note that `OfType<>` does both, filter and cast to the required type.

Another way is to not use generics at all and to work with the `object` type in the `Bar` class for maximum dynamic flexibility.

Type safety and dynamic flexibility are opponents.

Comment: Note that if the only reason for the interface is to mark the specific types you care about, it can be empty.

Comment: @PeterDuniho: Yes, this is called a marker interface. But even if this helps in indentifying all the `Baz<T>` the problem of doing something useful with and unknown `T` remains.

Comment: +1 for the `OfType<T>()` shortcut, but it still doesn't solve the problem in that I would have to modify `Bar`, which I am not allowed to do because it is code common to other projects.

Comment: You can add an interface to the inheritance list of `Bar<T>` for already existing members (or without any members as Peter Duniho mentioned in his comment) without breaking existing code.

Comment: Well, I could try proposing this, but it's like pulling teeth getting permission to change any of the common code.  If it were my own project I'd certainly do something like that, but they get really paranoid about this kind of thing here.

Answer (score 2):

If the `Bar<T>.MethodCommonToAllBar` method doesn't depend on the type `T`, you could define an interface to be common for all bars:

```
public interface IBar
{
    void MethodCommonToAllBar();
}

public class Bar<T> : Foo, IBar
{
    public void MethodCommonToAllBar()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Then you'll be able to cast any `Bar<T>` to this interface:

```
foreach (IBar bar in MyList.OfType<IBar>())
{
    bar.MethodCommonToAllBar();
}
```

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Thank you very much for your edits, I'm so sloppy even in a copy-paste.

Comment: As I mentioned above, I am not able to make alterations to the classes.  This or an in-between class would be my ideal solution, but my hands are tied since I can't alter the class structure at all.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there is such concepts as contravariance, covariance.

> In C#, covariance and contravariance enable implicit reference
>   conversion for array types, delegate types, and generic type
>   arguments.Covariance preserves assignment compatibility and
>   contravariance reverses it. (Eric Lippert)

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx

It might or it might not help you. Basically, if your class implements `IFoo<out T>`, you can treat that class as a `IFoo<object>` without knowing the actual generic type.

Comment: Interesting stuff, but I don't see anything in here that wouldn't require me to make alterations to the classes, which I'm not allowed to do.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
MyList.OfType<Bar<string>>().ToList()
    .ForEach(item => item.MethodCommonToAllBar());
```

Comment: I'd still need to know every possible subtype of Bar to run this on.  I guess it makes it 3 less lines per type, because it melds the ForEach into a single line, but it doesn't solve the problem that I don't know how many `T`s there will be and don't want to add new code every time somebody makes another `Bar<SomeOtherTypeIDidntThinkOf>`.