# Split a list of items with generic parameters into separate lists of each generic type

Tags: c#, linq, generics

I'm trying to solve a problem where I want to split a list up based on the type of a generic parameter of the items in the list.  The type may be different for each type.  Below is some demo code to try and explain what I need to do.

Note: This code will **not** compile as is because type T is not defined in FindDerivedItemsAndCallForEachT.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class BaseItem
{
}

public class DerivedItem<T> : BaseItem
{
}

public class Test
{
    public void FindDerivedItemsAndCallForEachT(List<BaseItem> list)
    {
        var derivedItems = from d in list.OfType<DerivedItem<T>>()
            select d;

        var listsOfDerivedItems = from d in derivedItems
            group d by d.GetType() into g
            select g.ToList();

        foreach (var listOfDerivedItem in listsOfDerivedItems)
        {
            HandleForTypeT(listOfDerivedItem);
        }
    }


    public void HandleForTypeT<T>(List<DerivedItem<T>> derivedList)
    {
        // do something with the provided list.
    }
}
```

So I have a list of BaseItems which may contain some derived items that take a generic parameter.  This parameter may be different for each item in the list.  What I want to do is find all the derived types in the list and then split them into separate lists of each generic type.  Then take each of those lists and pass them to another method for processing.

My approach may be completely wrong here so feel free to take another path.

My question is almost the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26555999/2301065).  The difference for me is that I don't want to call a method on the list items but pass them as a list to another method.  The derived items of each type T need to be processed together.

Comment: While it is possible to get out of this situation by using reflection, frankly this sounds like "help needed to implement a suspect solution to an unknown problem". I think you could get far more help value by explaining why you chose this design instead of classic polymorphism and possibly the Visitor pattern.

Comment: @Jon Thanks for your thoughts, I haven't actually written any code yet.  I'm just thinking about a possible design.  The more I think about it I don't think it will work because it goes against the design of generics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a "solution".  It uses reflection but (as noted by @Jon) the real problem may be the architecture itself.  My solution is likely to be different since the method HandleForType< T > will actually be in a separate class of type T and will be able to filter List< BaseItem > to find all Derived< T > itself.

Please feel free to improve the code as it may help others trying to do something similar.

References:
[SO Question that got me on the right track](https://stackoverflow.com/a/982495/2301065)
[Related MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b8ytshk6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace UnitTestProject1
{
    [TestClass]
    public class CheckFindDerivedItemsAndCallForEachT
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            var list = new List<BaseItem>();
            list.Add(new DerivedItem<string>());
            list.Add(new DerivedItem<int>());

            var test = new Test();

            test.FindDerivedItemsAndCallForEachT(list);
        }
    }

    public class BaseItem
    {
    }

    public class DerivedItem<T> : BaseItem
    {
    }

    public class Test
    {
        public void FindDerivedItemsAndCallForEachT(List<BaseItem> list)
        {
            var derivedItems = from d in list
                               where d.GetType().IsGenericType
                               && d.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(DerivedItem<>)
                               select d;

            var listsOfDerivedItems = from d in derivedItems
                                      group d by d.GetType() into g
                                      select g.ToList();

            // create generic type definition for lists
            var listGenericDefinition = typeof(List<>);

            foreach (var listOfDerivedItem in listsOfDerivedItems)
            {
                // all the lists should have at least one member which will be of the type that we need.
                Type itemType = listOfDerivedItem[0].GetType();
                Type listType = listGenericDefinition.MakeGenericType(itemType);

                // note use of dynamic is important.
                dynamic castList = Activator.CreateInstance(listType);
                foreach (dynamic item in listOfDerivedItem)
                {
                    castList.Add(item);
                }

                HandleForTypeT(castList);
            }
        }

        public void HandleForTypeT<T>(List<DerivedItem<T>> derivedList)
        {
            // do something with the provided list.
        }
    }
}
```